# Qt: How to list hidden windows?

Tags: qt, window, show

I am trying to `show()` a hidden MainWindow from my `main.cpp` (in fact all windows are hidden at this point). I tried doing something like this:

```
QList<QWindow*> windows = QApplication::allWindows();
for (int i = 0; i < windows.size(); ++i) {
    if (windows.at(i)->objectName() == "MainWindow")
        windows.at(i)->show();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

In Qt documentation in `QApplication::allWidgets()` there is an annotation :

> Note: Some of the widgets may be hidden.

As if this function wasn't listing hidden widgets and I suppose that's the same case with `allWindows()`, because I tested this piece of code when windows are not hidden and it worked.

Basically in the `void MainWindow::closeEvent` function I do:

```
    event->ignore();
    hide();
```

And then I want to be able to reopen the MainWindow when I click on the application's icon.

Does anyone have a better idea how to show a hidden window from `main.cpp` or can indicate if I am doing something wrong?

edit: this probably works, my issue lied somewhere totally different.

Comment: Did you try sample code here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets ? It should work, according to docs.

Comment: Interesting enough it doesn't work either.

Comment: But that would suggest that those functions I mentioned do list hidden files only for some reason they don't work as I'd expect them to in my case.

Comment: How do you know that your windows is hidden? Maybe it doesn't exists at all?

Comment: The thing I am testing right now is that the 'X' close button only hides the application and clicking again on the icon shows the previous window . So I can go back to the previous state by clicking on the "hidden icons" from the icon tray (not sure if I am using the correct vocabulary) - this is why I assume the windows still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for finding all of a particular kind of window in the Qt Object tree can be shortened:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren

```
QList <QMainWindow *> mainWindows = qApp->findChildren<QMainWindow *>();
foreach(QMainWindow * w, mainWindows)
{
    qDebug() << "Found a main window" << w->objectName() 
        << "isVisible?" << w->isVisible();
}
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild

Or if you know the name of the qobject:

```
QMainWindow * w = qApp->findChild<QMainWindow *>("My Named MainWindow");
if(w)
{
    qDebug() << "Found" << w->objectName() << "isVisible?" << w->isVisible();
}
```

`findChild` and `findChildren` can be used on any QObject or a subclass of QObject, and can be used to reflect out a pointer to any of their children.

```
MyMainWindow * w = qApp->findChild<MyMainWindow *>();
```

Also if you want any QWidget to not die or close the application if it is the last window to be closed, then use:

```
w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, false);
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop

```
qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

but then you have to explicitly put `qApp->close()` somewhere in your code.

Another related tool to all of this is `qobject_cast`; I like using it with QObject::sender();

```
// some slot connected to by multiple sources
void mySlot()
{
    QPushButton * b = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(QObject::sender());
    if(b)
    {
       qDebug() << "Push Button triggered" << Q_FUNC_INFO;
       b->setText("Ouch");
       b->setDisabled(true);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @phyatt! Your help is much appreciated, but somehow it doesn't work for me and I really don't know why. Basically the problem is that the list is empty even though all I did was hide the main window and the application is still running and when I access it through the hidden icons tray in the taskbar I go back to the previous state not new main window or anything like this.

Comment: It sounds like somehow `deleteLater` is getting called on your main window.  It might be that because no other object has a pointer to it, and you don't have it visible, that the `QEventLoop` cleaned it up. Can you store the pointer to the main window some other way so that the `QMenuItem` or `QAction` in the system tray can find the pointer?  Put a print statement in your Destructor for your main window, and put a print statement in your `closeEvent`.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, It was stupid of me not to think about this before. Everytime I wanted to reopen the app I was actually just creating another instance of the same app. The app uses mutex and if there in an app already running it just shows a message that the app in already open but doesn't create any windows so obviously there weren't any windows to be listed. Anyways thanks a lot @phyatt I'm marking your answer as correct as it indeed answers my initial question.